# Remove element depending on it's background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, attr

I'm trying to remove an element from a page based on it's background attribute.
Something like:

```
    if ( $('td').attr('background','backgroundimageurl')){this.remove();}
```

But this does not work any suggestions?

Comment: I feel bad, I should've specified it was an HTML attribute, sorry everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even shorter example:

```
$('td[background="backgroundimageurl"]').remove();
```

Do some reading on jQuery selectors. They can be really useful :)

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize you are selecting a css atribute. My example only works for HTML atributes.

Comment: This should be perfect because I was talking about HTML attributes, I will let you know if it works.

Comment: How come it won't work multiple times, I used this and it did not work properly: `$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Top.gif"]').remove();
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Left.gif"]').remove();
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Bottom.gif"]').remove();
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Right.gif"]').remove();`

Comment: It should work... Check whether the url is the same in the javascript and HTML. I think a trailing slash would prevent it from working.

Comment: The URLs are the same, the trailing slashes did not make a difference. How can I call this on the page load?

Comment: Like this:
`$(document).ready(function(){
//Your code here
});`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use filter to filter the result set based on your operations:

```
$( 'td' ).filter( function(){
   // return true of it matches, thus, keeping it in the object
   return $(this).css( 'backgroundImage' ) === 'someUrlOrWhatever';
}).remove();
```

Demo per roXon's request: http://jsfiddle.net/danheberden/9rTZj/

However, it would be better to do a check like

```
return /someDomain\.com\/path\/to\/whatever/.test( $( this ).css( 'backgroundImage' ) );
```

in the filter function. Different browsers will return different formatting for css rules, as roXon pointed out about the `===` approach won't work in FF because the returned string will be url("thePath") instead of url(thePath) like in webkit. Thus, just testing for the url value would be most flexible.

Comment: (P.S. I found an interesting issue... take a look at my answer, That's why I asked you to test in Mozilla your demo, **It won't work**)

Comment: @roXon - you didn't ask about mozilla (http://jsfiddle.net/danheberden/9rTZj/) but that's why i suggested the other route of using regex (which works in FF), so you don't have to worry about the url() formatting from the browser. I'll clarify that issue in the answer though :)

Comment: I deleted the 'test in Mozilla please' comment after 10 min.

Comment: And what if ALL td's had different images and the approach is to **find a specific one** (like the OP asked I think), would than your second example work?

Comment: Crap, i responded to this thinking it was a different answer (sry if you read it and was like wtf?)  - anyway, yes - the second approach would be good to find a specific pattern (url, image name, whatever) and only end up with that filtered result

Comment: @dan Thanks for responding, but I'm talking about a case where the background attribute is being used, for example td width=0 height =10px background=/directory/to/background_image.gif any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Yeah, just test the attr instead of background - `return $(this).attr( 'background' )` - if it's unset/not-there then it will return undefined (a falsy value)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is that in your code snippet, "this" is the current context (most likely the window).

This might do what you want:

```
$('td').each(function (i, e) {
  if (e.style.foo === "bar") {
    $(e).remove();
  }
});
```

each iterates through all of the elements that matched. i is the number of the loop, and e is the current element. So we test each element and then act when we find the one with the style we want.

Comment: Keep in mind that e.style.foo does not return info from CSS stylesheets, only inline styles set directly on the element.

Comment: look at my answer. There's another interesting crossbrowser issue

Answer (score -2):

Try this. When you were doing attr("background","backgroundurl") this was trying to set the background attr rather than find elements matching. This will do the trick.

```
if($("body").find("td").css("background-image") == "backgroundimageurl"){this.detach()};
```

Comment: Also that would only get the 'background' attr on the first `td`, not all of them. You'd have to include some kind of iteration.

Comment: find() will get all elements matching in dom, if I were to do $("#body").find("td:first"), then this would find only the first one.

Comment: definitely, but attr (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L851) will use the first element in the collection, unless you pass a function - though then you might as well be using `each` or `filter`.